# How to rewind in Go's text/scanner?

Tags: parsing, go, rune

I am using `text/scanner` package to parse some arbitrary expressions. I am currently trying to implement a `not in` option, that is, if the current identifier is `not`, and the next is `in`, parse it using function `notin(left, right)`, and otherwise we parse it as `negate(right)`.

I've essentially got the code to manage these cases however, I am unable to rewind the scanner in case the next token is not `in`. I've tried by recording the position and then reassigning it later, but to no avail and haven't been able to find a different solution.

```golang
func readToken(stream *scanner.Scanner) {
    switch stream.Scan() {
    case scanner.Ident:
        switch stream.TokenText() {
        case "in":
            in(left, right)
        case "not":
            oldPosition := stream.Position
            nextToken := stream.Scan()
            if nextToken == scanner.Ident {
                switch stream.TokenText() {
                case "in":
                    fmt.Println("notin")
                default:
                    // how do we rewind the scanner?
                    stream.Position = oldPosition 
                    fmt.Println("negate default")
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Println("negate no-ident")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I rewind the scanner when I don't find a valid identifier?

Edit, I also tried using `Peek()` as below, but that still changes the state to the point that I'd need to rewind as well.

```golang
// other code
case "not":
    nextIdent, err := getNextIdent(stream)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("negate no-ident")
    } else {
        switch nextIdent {
        case "in":
            fmt.Println("notin")
        default:
            fmt.Println("negate default")
        }
    }
// other code


func getNextIdent(s *scanner.Scanner) (string, error) {
    var nextIdent string

    ch := s.Peek()

    // skip white space
    for s.Whitespace&(1<<uint(ch)) != 0 {
        ch = s.Next()
    }

    if isIdentRune(ch, 0) {
        nextIdent = string(ch)
        ch = s.Next()
        nextIdent += string(ch)
        for i := 1; isIdentRune(ch, i); i++ {
            ch = s.Next()
            if s.Whitespace&(1<<uint(ch)) != 0 {
                break
            }
            nextIdent += string(ch)
        }
        return nextIdent, nil
    }

    return "",errors.New("not a ident")
}
```

Note, the code I've got is a forked from [Knetic/govaluate](https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate) combined with a [PR from GH user generikvault](https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate/pull/71) and some other forks. The full code can be found on my [Github profile](https://github.com/hoshsadiq/govaluate/)

Comment: Have you tried replacing `nextToken := stream.Scan()` with `nextToken := stream.Peek()`? Of course, you'll have to adapt some of your code.

Comment: You can't rewind a scanner. Your only option, if `Peek` is not sufficient, is to buffer the input, and scan it twice.

Comment: You don't mention how you are actually parsing, but if you are using something like recursive descent, there is no need for the scanner to make this distinction because the two uses of `not` are in disjoint contexts: one is a prefix operator; the other is part of an infix operator. You should know before you request the token which one would be valid. After you see a `not` token, a following `in` would either be required or illegal, depending upon which type of `not` it is.

Comment: @Federico `Peek()` gives you a single rune, which isn't enough to figure out what's the next token is.

Comment: @Flimzy I guess it doesn't necessarily need to be a rewind option as long as I can see if `not` comes after `in`. I've tried to buffer (providing I understood what you mean), but to no avail - see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the API references of `text/scanner`, I can't seem to find a way to rewind the scanner the way you want.

However, the `Peek()` method would get you the next rune without advancing the scanner. Inside the "not" case, you can use it to peek in advance to see if it matches.

Comment: `Peek()` only gives you 1 rune, which doesn't help. I tried using `Next()` too but that just changes the state as well which gets me back to need to rewind.

Comment: You can keep `Peek()`-ing as far as you wish. Since it doesn't change the state, you may even iterate the entire document.

Comment: I tried using `Peek()` in a loop but to it only returns the same rune, whereas `Next()` always returns the next run but it does change the state.

Comment: So `fmt.Printf("%v;%v;%v\n%v;%v;%v\n", s.Peek(), s.Peek(), s.Peek(), s.Next(), s.Next(), s.Next())` produces `32;32;32\n32;105;110`